# 'Subclassing' a Function in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, docx

I'm working with the `docx` library in Python, and I was hoping to create a subclass `NewStyleDoc` of the `Document` class from `docx`.  I attempted to do this as follows:

```
from docx import Document
class NewStyleDocument(Document):
    # stuff
```

And I received the error:

```
TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

Which means `Document` is actually a function.  (I verified this with `type(Document)`)  My question is: can I define a class that inherits all of the properties of `Document`?  My ultimate goals is simple: I just want to do:

```
doc = NewStyleDocument()
```

and have some custom fonts.  (Usually you have to modify styles each time you create a new document.)  Maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: If it is indeed a function, you may need [decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators).

Comment: Try determining the type of the object returned by the `Document` function, and subclass that instead.

Comment: Just call the original function from your new function, modifying the result. Or, if the old function returns an instance of a class, subclass *that*.

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/api.py#L17-L29) you'll have some work to do there.

Comment: Looks like the simplest way would be to create your own factory function called `NewStyleDocument` that calls `Document`, calls the `.add_styles`, then returns the result of that...

Comment: @MartijnPieters could you clarify your meaning of 'new function' in the former approach?  Are you suggesting I inherit from `object` but call `Document` in `__init__`?

Comment: By the way: you really **can't** subclass the `function` types: `class MyFunction(types.FunctionType):pass -> TypeError: type 'function' is not an acceptable base class`

Comment: @Jason: I don't know what you are trying to do here, and the `docx` package contains a large number of delegations (funcions and classes that abstract and delegate to other classes), so there is no easy quick answer here. I suspect that the returned instance is a [`docx.document.Document()` instance](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/document.py), which itself is a proxy class. You'll need to study the source code and figure out if you need to create another wrapping class or can just monkey-patch the right class here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method (as `docx.Document` appears to be a factory function) is probably to just let it do what it needs to so you don't repeat, and wrap around it:

```
from docx import Document

def NewStyleDocument(docx=None):
    document = Document(docx)
    document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)
    return document

mydoc = NewStyleDocument()
```

Comment: This did the trick for me.  I see that `docx=None` is essential, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Jason if you look at code that [Martijn posted](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/api.py#L17-L29) - it's a factory function - what we're doing here is just creating another factory function that  has the same signature, calls the original, you then call whatever you need to mutate that object, then you return it again... it's not inheritance but if it does what you need to do without code digging then... oh well... :)

Comment: @Jason thinking about it - you could make it a bit more future-proof by using `def NewStyleDocument(*args, **kwargs)` then calling `Document(*args, **kwargs)` but... probably not an issue in this case... but if the API is going to change it might be...

Comment: I see now.  For future readers: `docx = None` comes from the factory function upon which this answer is based.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the documentation.  Your issue seems to be you are using a constructor built into the module, not into the object.

```
Document objects¶
   class docx.document.Document[source]

   WordprocessingML (WML) document. Not intended to be constructed directly. Use docx.Document() to open or create a document.
```

So you need to add another layer in there (Docx.document.Document)